# How to spiderfy stacked POIs in CARTO's standard map?

Tags: carto, clustering, carto-js, markers

I'm creating [this map](https://kochizufan.carto.com/viz/619dd090-8cdf-11e6-91a7-0e05a8b3e3d7/public_map) on CARTO.

Some POIs are stacked even at max zoom level, so some POIs are impossible to be clicked.

Are there any methods to make these POIs spiderfied?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to show points  information that share the same location. Chris Whong did a great job on [this blog post](https://carto.com/blog/stacking-chips-a-map-hack/) to describe them and proposed a nice solution using some spatial SQL.

Comment: Hi, thank you for information. Given blog post is little difficult, I may take some times to understand..
Is this technique can use on CARTO's Map function?
Or, I must make some my own pages by using carto.js?

Comment: You can apply the SQL command within the Editor, [here](https://gist.github.com/ramiroaznar/9afe6c0e881e9adc6a5415cc9fbeaf4e) you have the template. Or you can try the first approaches with CARTO.js, using for instance Leaflet `MarkerCluster` and `spidify` methods.