# How to automatically separate two pins when a map is scaled in Carto

Tags: postgis, carto, cartography, carto-js, cartocss

I am building a map on Carto, i am mapping activities at building level in a city. Sometimes two activities occur in the same building, when the map is zoomed in (at building level) you can clearly see the different icons but when I zoom out the icons collide and you can finally see one only (others are masked behind).

I wonder if there is a way to automatically separated the icons when the map is scaled in order to keep the readability of each individual icon? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Jorge [in a previous answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/213625/41250), there are a wide diversity of ways to achieve what you are looking for. My favorites are *spidifying* and *stacking chips*.

The first alternative cannot be done directly within CARTO Editor, you have to use CARTO.js and `Markercluster` Leaflet's plugin. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/oriolbx/7518b5834d1b679759bda218871cb315) you have a working example. However, the second method can be implemented just using SQL:

```
WITH m AS (
        SELECT 
          array_agg(cartodb_id) id_list, 
          the_geom_webmercator, 
          ST_Y(the_geom_webmercator) y 
        FROM table_name
        GROUP BY the_geom_webmercator 
        ORDER BY y DESC
      ),
      f AS (
        SELECT  
          generate_series(1, array_length(id_list,1)) p, 
          unnest(id_list) cartodb_id, 
          the_geom_webmercator 
        FROM m
      )
    SELECT  
      ST_Translate(f.the_geom_webmercator,0,f.p*50) as the_geom_webmercator,
      f.cartodb_id
    FROM f, table_name q
    WHERE f.cartodb_id = q.cartodb_id
```

You only need to replace `table_name` with your dataset name and add in the last `SELECT` the fields you are interested in like this `q.field1`, `q.field2` and so on. In addition, depending on your zoom range you should change the offset parameter (in my case I have used `50`). [Here](https://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/raw/1e45bdd58994aee8293d/) you have a working example.

Comment: With the above sql method (which produces stacked icons), is there a way to alter the Y multiplier per zoom level. This would allow the stacks to remain tightly stacked across all zoom levels, instead of spreading out when you zoom in?

Comment: Yes, there is. In [the original one](https://carto.com/blog/stacking-chips-a-map-hack), the author (Chris Whong) used Javascript to change dynamically the `f` factor based on zoom. But [in this new version](https://gist.github.com/ramiroaznar/e150bf13af9ca085c8089962a27a2b16), another colleague used CartoCSS in order to obtain the same result.

Comment: -@ramiroaznar I notice the map from Chris Whong doens't have dynamic zoom offset enabled although he has added the js (not sure if something has broken at some stage). The function marker-transform: translate(x,y) seems to be what I have been after. Having the offset in the cartoCSS allows zoom dependent offsets. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: You are right. That's a very old post blog. Anyway, I recommend the solution you have chose because there is not js involved.